# Unknown Partition Table Error on Boot Randomly after Reboot: Conflicting Device Mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, 15.04

I get an error on the boot that I took a screen shot below. Also the output of the fdisk -l command is shown. sda: unkwown partition table is the error. And then conflicting device mode.

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 on an Asus UX301 dual boot with windows 8. The internal drive is ran as a raidx0 with two 256GB drives. I can boot into windows fine only Ubuntu seems to be the problem.

[image: Error result]

[image: fdisk -l results]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is basically that you're using motherboard-based software RAID (aka "fake RAID"). For whatever reason, your installation isn't recognizing that software RAID format, which is causing your problems.

I don't have a step-by-step solution to your problem (I avoid this type of RAID like the plague), but I recommend you start by reading the [Ubuntu Fake RAID HOWTO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto). If that doesn't help, then perhaps somebody with more experience with this type of RAID will be able to comment.

One more point, though: Your RAID uses the [GUID Partition Table (GPT),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) which means that `fdisk` is useless on that disk; you *must* use either GPT fdisk (`gdisk`) or something based on libparted (`parted` or GParted, for instance). The kernel's `unknown partition table` message is a manifestation of lack of support for your RAID configuration, but `fdisk`'s failure to display partitions is a manifestation of its lack of GPT support; you've got two different causes that happen to show similar symptoms. Furthermore, use of GPT means that Windows must be booting in EFI/UEFI mode. I don't know how you booted your computer, but you must be sure to install Ubuntu in EFI/UEFI mode; booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode will create new problems for yourself. The [Ubuntu Community wiki on UEFI installations,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) although somewhat disorganized, does a tolerable job with this subject; and my own [Linux on UEFI](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) page covers the pitfalls and procedures, too. Neither of these pages covers RAID explicitly, but if the RAID tools are set up properly, the RAID should be pretty transparent to the installation and boot mode.

Comment: Yes I have had this installation for about a year now with not much problems. The other day my battery died while the computer was on and this problem started. I know about the pitfalls with Fake Raid but at the time was the only possible way to install and do what I wanted. If I went back I probably would do something differently and just have two separate disks. But I do believe both installations are UEFI and not legacy. I don't think I could install otherwise but took me ages to get the system working with Fake RAID and dual-boot anyway.

Comment: Actually I would destroy it at this point and reinstall with two disks but I don't want to destroy the windows installation at this point.